# stack "Plan construction failed."

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to build a local hoogle server with the following command on a project, which is using `lts-11.1` as the resolver in `stack.yaml`

```
stack hoogle -- server --local --port=8080
```

It used to work, but now it fails with this error:

```
▸ stack hoogle -- server --local --port=8080
Hoogle isn't installed. Automatically installing (use --no-setup to disable) ...
Minimum version is hoogle-5.0. Found acceptable hoogle-5.0.17.6 in your index, installing it.

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for hoogle-5.0.17.6:
    haskell-src-exts-1.20.3 from stack configuration does not match >=1.21 && <1.22  (latest matching version is 1.21.0)
needed since hoogle is a build target.

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Set 'allow-newer: true' in /Users/leo/.stack/config.yaml to ignore all version constraints and build anyway.

  * Consider trying 'stack solver', which uses the cabal-install solver to attempt to find some working build configuration. This can be convenient when dealing with many complicated constraint
    errors, but results may be unpredictable.

  * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /Users/leo/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml:

haskell-src-exts-1.21.0@sha256:02421cacaa48c055551b8e5796efc543301b7ea9527a38e1385403d2b85512fb

Plan construction failed.
```

The `/Users/leo/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml` has `resolver: lts-13.15` in it.

When I was working on that project a long while ago, I was using `ghc8.2.2` with `lts-11.1`. I recently reinstalled everything on my laptop, including `haskell-stack`, now my `stack --version` is `1.9.3 x86_64`, and hoogle can't be built. Not sure if it's because of my stack version or something else.

How can I fix it?

Comment: There is a recommended action right near the end. It looks like it would address the issue. What happened when you implemented that recommendation?

Comment: That actually worked. Thanks!